# Grails pagination not working after move from v2 to v5

Tags: grails

I'm migrating a big application from Grails 2.2.5 to Grails 5. I've just run into what seems to be a puzzlingly basic problem. The 'paginate' tag no longer generates the same code as before. I have this in a GSP:

`<g:paginate action="directClients" total="${totalCount}" params="${params}" class="pull-right" maxsteps="5"/>`

In v2, this results in the following (working) HTML:

```
<div class="pagination pull-right">
  <ul>
    <li class="prev disabled"><span>Previous</span></li>
    <li class="active"><span>1</span></li>
    <li><a href="/admin/user/directClients?max=20&amp;offset=20" class="step">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/admin/user/directClients?max=20&amp;offset=40" class="step">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="/admin/user/directClients?max=20&amp;offset=60" class="step">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="/admin/user/directClients?max=20&amp;offset=80" class="step">5</a></li>
    <li class="disabled"><span>...</span></li>
    <li><a href="/admin/user/directClients?max=20&amp;offset=300" class="step">16</a></li>
    <li class="next"><a href="/admin/user/directClients?max=20&amp;offset=20" class="step">Next</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In v5, though, it results in this, which doesn't display correctly:

```
<span class="currentStep">1</span>
<a href="/admin/user/directClients?max=20&amp;offset=20" class="step">2</a>
<a href="/admin/user/directClients?max=20&amp;offset=40" class="step">3</a>
<a href="/admin/user/directClients?max=20&amp;offset=60" class="step">4</a>
<a href="/admin/user/directClients?max=20&amp;offset=80" class="step">5</a><span class="step gap">..</span>
<a href="/admin/user/directClients?max=20&amp;offset=300" class="step">16</a>
<a href="/admin/user/directClients?max=20&amp;offset=20" class="nextLink">Next</a>
```

So the 'paginate' tag is now rendering something quite different, which is odd. Any suggestions? This is Grails 5.3.0.

Comment: The grails taglibs have been poorly (or maybe "not"?) documented since around grails 3, so it's not really clear what this tag should generate.  It looks like the general capability is the same though, and your styles just differ.  Are you including default stylesheets?  Had you overridden specific styles in your own stylesheets?

Comment: It seems that the issue is that in v2.2.5 it used TwitterBootstrapTagLib.groovy for pagination, whereas in the latest it uses the Grails Core taglib. The line in runtime.groovy 'grails.plugins.twitterbootstrap.fixtaglib = true' clearly doesn't work as it used to.

Comment: "It seems that the issue is that in v2.2.5 it used TwitterBootstrapTagLib.groovy" - If you mean Grails did that by default, I don't think that is the case.  The `core` `paginate` tag for 2.2.5 is defined at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/v2.2.5/grails-plugin-gsp/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/taglib/RenderTagLib.groovy#L340.